# I need to call a method from another class that has dependencies

Tags: ruby

I am unit testing and my test is running two tests due to me having to call the class and then the method so I get one assertion and one failure.

```
assert_equal(Class, ClassName.new('query', 'test').upload_file(results_csv, 'test'), 'tests do not match')

assert_equal(Class, ClassName.new('query', 'test').upload_file(results_csv, 'test'), 'tests do not match')
```

I get one assertion and one failure due to the unit test running two tests.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: I have: a class with several methods that I am trying to unit test. I wrote a unit test for it that checks that one of the methods is returning the right class however as you can see above it calls the full class and then the individual method so I get one failure (from when it runs the whole class) and one assertion from when it runs just the method. Is there a way to eliminate it running the whole class?